# Remove Samsung Daily screen

Tags: samsung, home-screen, samsung-galaxy-s-9

The Samsung Daily screen was automatically added to my home screens. It appears when I scroll one step extra to the left. That happens sometimes and I do not wish this information to come up.

From what I read as a solution to this problem, you change a setting when you are on the screen. However, all I get is this error message about a network problem. My network is working fine. When I dismiss this error message, the Samsung Daily screen disappears.

How do I remove Samsung Daily?

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows a very poor connection, the opposite of a network working fine.

Comment: True, but I can have any signal strength, still getting this message.

Comment: If this is what I think it is, then try tap-and-holding an empty screen on the home screen, select Settings, then there may be an option called "Add media page to Home screen" or similar that says "Samsung Daily". (Otherwise, refer to [this animated guide](https://videotron.tmtx.ca/en/topic/samsung_galaxys20/turning_off_samsung_daily.html#step=1))

Comment: I did tap and hold, was able to scroll the screen to samsung daily and found a toggle! So you almost nailed it! Grateful @AndrewT.